# Demonstrating the byte ordering of a long integer

Tags: c, endianness

> Write a simple C program to determine the size in bytes of a long integer on your computer and demonstrate the byte ordering.

I am using the Visual Studio 2008 express edition. I did the first part of the program but I didn't do the second. What do I have to do to demonstrate the byte ordering?

Answer (score 2):

Create a number with a specific byte pattern: Something like: 0x1234ABCD

Then, when you output individual bytes, you can see the byte ordering.